# после запроса отображается кракозябры

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public void add(Clip clip) {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO top_clip (name, trek, view) VALUES (?,?,?)";

    try (Connection con = Connect.getConnect();
         PreparedStatement preparedStatement =
                 con.prepareStatement(sql)) {

        preparedStatement.setString(1, clip.getName());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, clip.getTrek());
        preparedStatement.setLong(3, clip.getView());

        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: где вы смотрите эти крякозябры? может там нужно указать кодировку при подключении к бд?

Comment: очевидно, проблема в кодировке, нужно разбираться

Comment: Я смотрю через intellij idea.И в подключении я указал кодировку useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8

Comment: Не в подключении нужно указывать кодировку, а непосредственно в поле выставлять при создании таблицы, которое использует строку

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: изменил кодировку ALTER TABLE top_clip CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci; и выполнил еще один запрос, не помогло

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо всем, я уже решил проблему. Проблема была в том что я на вход подавал кракозябры.

Comment: Интересное решение